# Minimizing an unknown system's output

Tags: optimization, np-complete

Let we have an unknown system with two inputs and two outputs.
 inputs $x=[x_1 x_2]$ and outputs $y=[y_1 y_2 ]$

The system have the following properties

$ y_1 = f_1(x_1,x_2)$ ; $y_2 = f_2(x_1,x_2) $

I don't really know $ f_1 $ and $ f_2 $ but for given $ x $ the system can generate $y$

Find $x$ which minimizes $(y_1+y_2)/2$

$ 1\leq x_1,x_2\leq $2

[Note : the system actually have $n$ numbers of input and output but for simplification I assumed $n=2$]

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical procedure of some sort? For an analytical solution given $f_1,f_2$?

Comment: I really don't know functions $f_1 , f_2 $ ; numerical solution would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

One class of methods commonly used for such purposes are the [gradient descent methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). The linked wiki article gives even the pseudocode and an example.

For more thoughts, consider reading chapter 10 in [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), especially sections 10.5 (Powell's Methods or Direction Set Methods), 10.6 (Gradient Descent) and 10.9 (Simulated Annealing).

Most such techniques seek **local** extrema (as opposed to **global** ones). If you want **global** extrema, without any assumptions on $f_1,f_2$, you have to restart the local method in multiple positions of the search space, and then choose the largest/smallest of the received candidates.